# Extracting asset from swf file?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash, symbols

As I am building a Flex framework for minigames, I plan to bundle a bunch of graphic assets (movieclip symbols) into a single swf file, which I will load into my Flex application, before extracting the symbols from the swf file for use in my application. My question is this: how do I do this through actionscript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use EMBED and you don't want to load the assets on runtime I recommend you exporting the swf as an SWC.

This way, you can browse SWC files from actionscript. You can event check on compile time that a sub-movieclip inside another movieclip exists.

If you are using flex compiler then remember adding this when you compile:

```
-library-path C:\path\to\your\file.swc
```

If you're using FDT you have an option to auto add the SWC as arguments.

Here's [a demo](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/fileadmin/features_swf/swc.htm) on how to do it with FDT. Not sure which tool are you using. If it's the commercial Flex Builder the process should be similar.

I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: +1 for recommending the SWC approach -- I actually hadn't thought of that one. Not having to the ship the extra SWF could be an advantage in some cases, although for Web-based apps it could also result in a much bigger SWF. Nonetheless depending on the circumstances it's nice to be reminded it's an option.

Comment: Thanks. Is A solution, not THE solution. Is very useful for those cases in which the assets don't change often and file size is not essential "E.g. interactive app".
I strongly reccomend use runtime assets at the same time you use SWC for those files that might need to be changed. We don't want to re/compile everything just to change an image, right? :)

Comment: You can also compile against a RSL (runtime shared library, basicly a swc loaded at runtime), that way you can still updated the swc later and write it strong typed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to create an asset/icon library AS file.

something along the lines of

```
package 
{

public class IconLibrary
{

    /*
    *  Framework Icons
    */

    [Embed (source="../assets/fof_graphics.swf", symbol="clapperboard_icon")]
    public static const clapperBoardIcon:Class;
    [Embed (source="../assets/fof_graphics.swf", symbol="clapperboard_over_icon")]
    public static const clapperBoardOverIcon:Class;
    [Embed (source="../assets/fof_graphics.swf", symbol="close_button")]
    public static const closeButton:Class;
    [Embed (source="../assets/fof_graphics.swf", symbol="close_over")]
    public static const closeOverButton:Class;

    public function IconLibrary()
    {
    }

  }

}
```

Then all you need to do is

```
source="{IconLibrary.clapperBoardIcon}"
```

or whatever the name of the asset you wish to show.

Answer (score 0):

Lot's of good solutions here, here's one for if you are loading the swf at runtime and want to extract assets, you can do the following in your loader complete event listener:

```
var c:Class = Class(LoaderInfo(e.target).applicationDomain.getDefinition("myClassDefinitionName"));
```

This will store the asset from the swf as a Class object so you can create instances of it like so:

```
var asset:MovieClip = new c();
```